# How do I merge one nested dictionary and one simple dictionary while changing the value in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, merge, zip

I have two dictionaries like this:

```
dict1 = {'foo': 3.0, 'bar': 2.69, 'baz': 3.0}

dict2 = {'foo': {'11-abc1': 0.47}, 'bar': {'11-abc1': 0.30, '12-abc1': 0.0}, 'baz': {'14-abc1': 0.47}}
```

Now I want to merge these two dictionaries while multiplying the values. The output should look like this:

```
dict3 = {'foo': {'11-abc1': 3.0 * 0.47}, 'bar': {'11-abc1': 
 2.69 * 0.30, '12-abc1': 2.69 * 0.0}, 'baz': {'14-abc1': 3.0 * 0.47}}
```

What would be the most efficient way to do that?

Comment: Iterate over items in `dict1`, for each iterate over keys in related subdict of `dict2`, for each key take value and multiply it with value from `dict1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
dict1 = {'foo': 3.0, 'bar': 2.69, 'baz': 3.0}
dict2 = {'foo': {'11-abc1': 0.47}, 'bar': {'11-abc1': 0.30, '12-abc1': 0.0}, 'baz': {'14-abc1': 0.47}}
new_dict = {a:{c:d*dict1[a] for c, d in b.items()} for a, b in dict2.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'bar': {'12-abc1': 0.0, '11-abc1': 0.8069999999999999}, 'foo': {'11-abc1': 1.41}, 'baz': {'14-abc1': 1.41}}
```

Using string formatting to show how code works:

```
dict1 = {'foo': 3.0, 'bar': 2.69, 'baz': 3.0}
dict2 = {'foo': {'11-abc1': 0.47}, 'bar': {'11-abc1': 0.30, '12-abc1': 0.0}, 'baz': {'14-abc1': 0.47}}
new_dict = {a:{c:"{}*{}".format(d, dict1[a]) for c, d in b.items()} for a, b in dict2.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'bar': {'12-abc1': '0.0*2.69', '11-abc1': '0.3*2.69'}, 'foo': {'11-abc1': '0.47*3.0'}, 'baz': {'14-abc1': '0.47*3.0'}}
```

Edit: Summing the final values:

```
import itertools
s = {'bar': {'12-abc1': 0.0, '11-abc1': 0.8069999999999999}, 'foo': {'11-abc1': 1.41}, 'baz': {'14-abc1': 1.41}}
new_s = list(itertools.chain(*[b.items() for a, b in s.items()]))
final_data = {a:sum(i[-1] for i in b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(new_s, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])}
```

Output:

```
{'12-abc1': 0.0, '11-abc1': 2.2169999999999996, '14-abc1': 1.41}
```

Comment: If I want to do a merge of the n-nested dictionaries and sum the values up like: {'12-abc1': 0.0, '11-abc1': 0.8069999999999999+1.41, '14-abc1': 1.41}, do you have a nice way to do that? Thanks!